# Copy Constructor of Stack using Linked Lists

Tags: c++

First making a copy constructor for linked lists was difficult and now this stack. I almost wanted to hit my head with something but then I thought of Stack Overflow guys. So here is the problem:
Consider One thing You can not change the list.h or stack.h or its constructor even.
// In list.h

```
template <class T>
struct ListItem
{
    T value;
    ListItem<T> *next;
    ListItem<T> *prev;

    ListItem(T theVal)
    {
        this->value = theVal;
        this->next = NULL;
        this->prev = NULL;
    }
};

/* This is the generic List class */
template <class T>
class List
{
    ListItem<T> *head;

public:

    // Constructor
    List();

    // Copy Constructor
    List(const List<T>& otherList);

}
// In list.cpp

template <class T>
List<T>::List()
{
    head=NULL;
}

template <class T>
List<T>::List(const List<T>& otherList)
{
// I have code working for this part        
}

template <class T>
List<T>::~List()
{
}
// In stack.h (includes list.cpp)

template <class T>
class Stack
{
    List<T> list;

public:

    Stack();

    Stack(const Stack<T>& otherStack);

    ~Stack();

    void push(T item);
    T top();
    T pop();
};
// remember top(); pop(); push() functions are working properly in stack.cpp file.
// In stack.cpp (includes stack.h)

    Stack(const Stack<T>& otherStack){
    }
template <class T>
void Stack<T>::push(T item)
{
}

template <class T>
T Stack<T>::top()
{
}

template <class T>
T Stack<T>::pop()
{
}
```

there is an object s containing elem from 0 to 100. 100 being on the top.
 Now we copy something like this:-

```
Stack<int> s2(s);
```

I don't know how on Earth to access otherStack elements. I mean of course its a linked list. But it is in Stack.cpp, what can I do to access it and also how to make a copy constructor for this stack (Working code would be preferable). And Please be supportive this time. Thanks.
NOTE: You can't change any constructor. It has to be the way it is. I hope every body this time gets my query.

Comment: If your `List`'s copy construct works correctly, then the implicitly generated copy constructor should work fine for your `stack` -- it just contains a `List`, which will be copy constructed using `List(List const &)`.

Comment: @JerryCoffin You mean something like this:-                                      
list.List<T> Stack(otherStack) // this is not working. Error:-> inproper use of function.

Comment: No.  He means delete your stack copy constructor declaration and implementation, then just copy one stack to another as you would any other object.

Comment: @jerryCoffin Can you please write down the code with comments. it would be a great favor.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley A little code would be helpful here

Comment: `Stack<int> s1; Stack<int> s2(s);` -- That copies s2 from s1. Just remove your current declaration and implementation of Stack's copy constructor, because the compiler will implicitly generate one that does the correct thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your `List`'s copy constructor works correctly, your `Stack` should be fine using the copy constructor generated implicitly by the compiler. That being the case, the complete code for a stack can look something like this:

```
template <class T>
class Stack { 
    List<T> data;
public:
    void push(T d) { data.add(data.begin(), d); }
    T front() { assert(!data.empty()); return data.front(); }
    void pop() { asset(!data.empty()); data.delete(data.begin()); }
};
```

We don't have to define a copy constructor for Stack, because List's copy constructor will be used to copy the `data` member (and that's the only data member of `Stack`, so copying it is also sufficient to copy the `Stack`).

Comment: Just In case I have to write copy constructor for stack. how would I proceed. Assuming I don't have linked list copy constructor.

Comment: @CerebralGarcon: The short (and correct) answer is: Just don't do that.

Comment: I have homework and they say if you bring any changes to header files you will be penalized. According to your method, I have to comment out copy construction declaration in  header file. This would cause me trouble. Is there a way that I don't comment out anything in header file but do any thing in cpp file and yet your method works.

Comment: @CerebralGarcon: Oh god. Well, if you really must have a copy constructor, it would be something like: `Stack(Stack const &other) : data(other.data) {}` (and when you're done, help your teacher find a job for which he's competent -- as a plumber or janitor, perhaps).